# Connection timeout issue sending email in Django

Tags: django, email, smtp, connection-timeout

I read from

http://www.packtpub.com/article/friends-via-email-social-web-application-django-1.0

and follow the steps:
=> And change my 
setting.py

```
SITE_HOST = '127.0.0.1:8000'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'KSO Publisher <soeng@xxxx.com.kh>'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.xxxx.com.kh'
EMAIL_PORT = '25'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myusernamea@xxxx.com.kh'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

after I go to the command line

```
python@python-desktop:~/workspace/kso$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jul 22 2009, 15:35:03) 
[GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> emails = send_mail('Subject', 'Body of the message.','soeng@xxxx.com.kh',['pythonkhmer@gmail.com'])
```

I got the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/core/mail.py", line 345, in send_mail
    connection=connection).send()
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/core/mail.py", line 271, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/core/mail.py", line 166, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/core/mail.py", line 131, in open
    local_hostname=DNS_NAME.get_fqdn())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/smtplib.py", line 244, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/smtplib.py", line 310, in connect
    raise socket.error, msg
error: (110, 'Connection timed out')
```

Anybody know what exactly the problem.And how Can I sent mail using django framworks

Reference I have read:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-and-smtpconnection-classes
- http://ltslashgt.com/2007/07/02/gmail-and-django/
- http://bakingnoodles.com/2009/03/command-line-email-with-django-and-gmail/comment-page-1/#comment-432

Answer (score 15, accepted):

'Connection timed out' means Django couldn't connect to your email server.
Type this on a command line:

```
telnet smtp.xxxx.com.kh 25
```

You should get a response from the email server, something like:

```
220 rufus Python SMTP proxy version 0.2
```

If you don't get a response,you have found the problem.

Here's a handy command to run a local development server, on Linux:

```
sudo /usr/lib/python2.6/smtpd.py -n -c DebuggingServer 127.0.0.1:25
```

Comment: If its a slow 220 ready response, django send_email will also fail with a SMTP timeout error.  One reason why it could be slow is that the mail server is performing an IDENT lookup on the connecting client and doesn't give the 220 ready response till its done.  Haven't found a way around this yet, a max timeout flag would be nice if you wait a longer time for this to complete.

Comment: It is showing `Trying 208.xxx.xxx.xxx...` nothing else. Is it a connection issue? Everything is working with same settings in my local machine

Comment: Since macOS 10.13, telnet is no longer included.  Use nc instead, i.e. something like `nc smtp.xxxx.com.kh 25`.

Answer (score 1):

You code looks correct, so I think there is a problem with your settings.  Are you positive that specified the `EMAIL_HOST` and `EMAIL_PORT` correctly?

Note: Its `EMAIL_USE_TLS` not `MAIL_USE_TLS` and you can set your from address (3rd parameter in send_mail function) to `None` if you want it to take your `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` value.